# How is interval fetch setting state in sync with fetched data in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an interval fetching data and updating state if data returned is not null.  Somehow if data being returned is updated and the set state is called, it will eventually stop re-rendering and the state will match the data before being set and stop re-rendering:

```
const [taskData, setTaskData] = useState({
   to_do: {
     title: 'To Do',
     tasks: [],
   },
   unassigned: {
     title: 'Unassigned',
     tasks: [],
   },
 });

useInterval(() => {
   const getTasksData = async () => {
     data = await getData();
     console.log('data ', data.data.to_do);
     console.log('task data', taskData.to_do);

     if (data.data !== null) setTaskData(data.data);
   };
   if (hasAccessToken) getTasksData();
 }, 5000);
...
return (
   <>
      {console.log('Rerender')}
   </>
```

This is what the console.log will look like:

```
Rerender
data  {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(3)}
task data {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(0)}
Rerender
data  {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(4)}
task data {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(4)}
Rerender
data  {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(5)}
task data {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(5)}
data  {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(6)}
task data {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(6)}
data  {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(7)}
task data {title: "To Do", tasks: Array(7)}
```

Notice how rendering stops

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `getData`?

Comment: Looks like you had the right idea, it is a mock fetch and for whatever reason messed it up, but it works with a real API call.

Comment: Ok, so you found the problem, that's the important thing.